# Google AMP «Нет нужных структурированных данных». Как узнать в чем именно проблема?

Tags: seo, amp

Приветствую всех, кто сможет чем-либо помочь.

Использую для одного из проектов микроразметку от schema org для оформления расширенных карточек AMP страниц. Проект занимается интернет-торговлей, соответственно, страница размечается типом (Product ) Но, Google через Search Console сообщает мне: *"Нет нужных структурированных данных"*. Но в чем конкретно ошибка - не указывает.

Самое интересное, что эта же AMP страница успешно проходит валидацию и у AMP валидатора через "#development=1" и у инструмента проверки структурированных данных в Search Console. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?
Собственно, разметка страницы через application/ld+json:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "http://schema.org/",
"@type": "Product",
"name": "XXXXXXXX",
"description": "XXXXXXXX",
"brand": {
    "@type":"Thing",
    "name":"XXXXXXXX"
},
"offers": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "priceCurrency": "RUB",
    "price": "1740.00",
    "priceValidUntil": "2016-07-01",
    "itemCondition": "http://schema.org/UsedCondition",
    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
    "seller": {
        "@type":"Organization",
        "name":"XXXXXXXX"
    }
},
"image":"https://XXXXXXXX.XX/XXXX/XXX.png"
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно тут есть ответ: [полное руководство по интеграции AMP на русском](http://wfi.lomasm.ru/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9.wfi_%D0%B2_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83_%D1%81%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8_wfi_%D0%B8_accelerated_mobile_pages)

Была такая ошибка, действовал по статье, мне помогло, описать блок image развернуто, так

```
div itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject"

meta itemprop="url" content="---"

meta itemprop="width" content="---"

meta itemprop="height" content="---"

/div
```

Вместо

```
meta itemprop="image" content="---"
```

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем за советы. Проблема решилась с выходом релиза Google AMP Validator. Теперь валидатор сообщает об ошибках в полном объеме.
Причина ошибки была (цитата из Search Console):

> Атрибут "style" не подходит для тега "span".

Иными словами, на AMP страницах не допускается использование атрибута **style** для тега **span**

Comment: На AMP страницах не допускается использование атрибута style для всех элементов ХТМЛ5, т.е. не допускается использование стилей внутри элемента body.